# AWS Elemental Live - Where do i find the Live IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elemental

I'm trying to work with AWS Elemental live  and I've manage to do the following:

• create a channel and an endpoint with AWS Elemental MediaPackage
• configure channel, input and output with AWS Elemental MediaLive
• stream a random video using OBS, and check it's properly showing by using the "play" link on the AWS console

My next step would be to test out the Graphic Overlay, so i checked [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elemental-live/latest/ug/static-graphic-overlay-commands.html) but i can't figure out where to find the Live IP.

Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to work with static overlay on AWS Elemental Live (On-prem hardware), then you are referring to the correct documentation. And you would use the Elemental Live Encoder IP address. Which can be found through the web-interface navigating to Settings --> Network --> Current Settings.

If you are trying to work with image overlays on AWS MediaLive Channel, the correct document to refer is [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/working-with-image-overlay.html).

Comment: We do not have any hardware. 
The idea is to add a an UI layer on a stream video pushed to MediaLive.
Thanks for the aswer, gonna check the  doc know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Elemental Live Ingest Endpoint IP as a Live IP Address.